# nm results with trailing numbers in symbol names

Tags: nm, xtensa

I have an empty program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `nm path/to/exe --format=sysv` I get numbers in the symbol names
e.g `file_mtx_85` and `free_fn_89`.

With different program I can get duplicates like `var_101` and `var_102`.
I think the duplication is because I have more than one symbol with that name, but why do I get numbers in the symbol names and what do they mean?

I'm compiling with Xtensa compiler.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag your compiler and system I can't reproduce with GCC on Debian.

Comment: You are right, It happens to me only with Xtensa and not with GCC